# Как поменять цвет персонализации?

Tags: c#, windows-10

Надо поменять цвет в персонализации Windows 10, кодом C#.

Не могу найти примеров, как это сделать через C#.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я не дам решение, но я дам тебе способ найти решение.

Этот цвет полюбому записывается реестр. Запускаешь RegMon и меняешь этот цвет вручную и сохраняешь настройки.
Смотришь по какому адресу было изменено значение в реестре.

Потом пишешь код на шарпе который вносит аналогичные изменения на необходимый тебе цвет.

Но т.к. запись реестра не зарефрешит юай тебе будет дополнительно необходимо найти способ рефрешнуть explorer.exe. Самый простой способ - убить процесс и запустить, но вероятнее всего есть способ рефрешнуть через какую-то команду WinApi. Так что если тебе нужно - можешь заморочится и найти что за команда.

Comment: это больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, правильно сделал, что не написал сразу ответ, а дал путь потому, что я как раз делаю программу для того, чтобы опробовать свои силы и научиться новому. Спасибо, Андрей :)